# zoom pinch functionality on image shown from a url in blackberry?

Tags: blackberry, pinchzoom

I am preparing a Blackberry app in which I prepare an HTTP connection and from a URL I display an image on the screen.
Now on touch listener I am showing this image on other screen and want to perform Zoom-pinch functionality with that image from URL.

The image is not in my device memory, it is directly shown from the HTTP connection. I want to run this app on 5.0+ devices.
Please suggest how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Try following steps:***

1. Get the image from URL.
2. Convert the image to [EncodedImage](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/EncodedImage.html).
3. Create a [ZoomScreen](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/extension/container/ZoomScreen.html) instance and display it.

***Creating and displaying a ZoomScreen***

```java
private void showImage(EncodedImage image) {
    synchronized (UiApplication.getEventLock()) {
        UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(new ZoomScreen(image));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanx rupak, I did seen that feature of BB but I thought It will just zoom my image, as its name specify. I used when you suggest and got success. thanx alot again. its working fine.